# How to work with utf-8 strings in java without allocating a new String object but as part of byte array instead?

Tags: java, scala, utf-8

I have place of my code where I want to read from binary format which include utf-8 strings.

Also I don't want *any* allocations in this place because they summon GC which pauses the world which kinda bad for me.

I can work perferctly well with most of my primitives and arrays except for strings because java is an "object oriented language" and emphasises on heavy usage of objects (= allocations). And it does not provide standard way of working with utf-8 strings without allocations as it has immutable object one.
So, what i need from this stuff - validate, extract `Char` and not to create any other objects. I.e. i should be able to put this thing pool or other place, initialise  with `data: Array[Byte]` and `offset: Int` and `length: X`, make no copy. `CharIterable` thing with ability to refurbish this object to other string.

So, should I do this by hand or someone already have done this?

Comment: Are you sure that you're not optimizing things prematurely? It's a bit unclear to me what you're really trying to achieve; can you give some example code? Also, different GCs handle stop-the-world events differently - are you sure these are a problem?

Comment: *"GC which pauses the world"* Have you considered using a GC that does not pause the world? Or, makes "stop the world" so rare that you don't have to worry about it?

Comment: I have considered ZGC but allocation rates usually hit large values and this results in some requests process longer they should be and this happens more frequent than I want to. Reducing GC have already show its positive effects, so i aim to have zero allocations per request and epsilon GC.

Comment: totally without allocations will be difficult (at least for Java) - but maybe a  `CharBuffer` can help, but hard to say

Comment: Allocations don't (always) pause the world. In a well written program they (almost) never do. You are mistaken about that. Especially, if you are talking about "allocations per request": if you are seeing _those_ stopping the world, your heap really, really needs tuning. This should never happen.

Comment: Code without allocations-per-request works faster than code with ton of allocations per request, and epsilon will work faster than ZGC.

Comment: GC pause time doesn't really have anything to do with the number of allocations.  It has to do with the number of reachable objects, and reducing the number of reachable objects is often (paradoxically) easier with immutability (which generally results in more allocations).

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you _have_ to be on the JVM? If so why? It sounds to me like you are on the JVM, and yet actively trying to fight the JVM, and I wonder if you are not better off implementing your program in Rust or even C/C++.

Comment: It would take months to convince ppl that rust actually a thing and even more time to get all approvals and even more time to rewrite stuff to rust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could try to directly call the low-level libraries that String uses internally, like [`CharsetDecoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html#decode(java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20java.nio.CharBuffer,%20boolean)) which can decode from a ByteBuffer into a pre-allocated CharBuffer.

But you may be overdoing this, I'd measure if using String (and the associated object allocations) are really a problem first.